# Android border around textview just on the base and partially on the right and left walls

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to get a border on the base of my android text view, it should look something like the count down -1:29 timer. I know I can create a image and put it on the background, but I need it to be a layout xml kinda thingy so that it adjusts with size of the text within for all phones.

[image: cab booking request]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a 9-patch image that can stretch horizontal and place it as a background. That is all you need.

Comment: Why didn't I think of that.. Thanks.